# Symfony 2 - Form select options database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm beginner in Symfony 2.

I'm trying to display a form with a "select" where is the "options" from a query.

I put the following code in my form :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Bloc\MainBundle\Entity\Table;
use Bloc\MainBundle\Entity\Table2;

public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $table = new Table();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($table , array('attr' => array('role' => 'form')))
        ->add('num', 'integer', array('label' => 'Numéro', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('nom_emetteur', 'text', array('label' => 'Emetteur', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('numero', 'entity', array('class' => 'BlocMainBundle:Table2', 'property' => 'numero'))
        ...
}
```

And I have the following error:

```
Neither the property "numero" nor one of the methods "getNumero()", "isNumero()", "hasNumero()", "__get()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Bloc\MainBundle\Entity\Table".
```

I understand that the error tells me that "numero" is not in the entity Table but I question the entity Table2.
I must miss something, but I do not know where ...

My entity definition looks like this :
Table 1:

```
<?php...
class Table
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="num", type="integer")
     */
    private $num;

    //Getter and setter...
}
```

Table 2

```
<?php

namespace Bloc\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Fournisseur
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bloc\MainBundle\Entity\Table2Repository")
 */
class Table2
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="integer")
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * Set numero
     *
     * @param integer $numero
     * @return Fournisseur
     */
    public function setNumero($numero)
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numero
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNumero()
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }
    ...
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Can you post your entity definitions for `Table` and `Table2`?

Comment: "numero" should probably be a foreign key for Table2. Need to see your entities to answer this question.

Comment: I have not yet created a relationship between my two entities, I do that later

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not have the relationship set then you need to tell the FormBuilder to not map it to a field.

```
->add('numero', 'entity', array(
    'mapped'   => false, 
    'class'    => 'BlocMainBundle:Table2',
    'property' => 'numero',
));
```

To accomplish the options the way that you want (using multiple fields for the option text) you need to use a `choice` type and build your options list like this:

```
->add('numero', 'choice', array(
    'mapped'  => false,
    'choices' => $this->buildChoices()
));

protected function buildChoices() {
    $choices          = [];
    $table2Repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BlocMainBundle:Table2');
    $table2Objects    = $table2Repository->findAll();

    foreach ($table2Objects as $table2Obj) {
        $choices[$table2Obj->getId()] = $table2Obj->getNumero() . ' - ' . $table2Obj->getName();
    }

    return $choices;
}
```

Comment: If I want to return my options two properties of my table as number and name, I am forced to create a setter and getter in my entity Table2 ?

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand.  You're trying to use the values in the field `numero` from `Table2` for the options in a select field, correct?

Comment: I struggled to find the right words ; i would like this result in my render `<select ...><option ...>112 - name1</option><option>113 - name2` ; not only "numero", but "numero" and "name" wich are two fields in `Table2`

Comment: Ok, give me a minute or two and I'll update my answer with the right way to use one field as the value and another as the option text.

Comment: I read the documentation which gives an almost similar example but unfortunately I have another error "Expected argument of type "object or array", "integer" given "... I'll keep looking, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Made it back to a computer where I could test it and updated the answer with the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this solution. Its a simply and from [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage) of symfony2. I m use this

```
->add('numero', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'BlocMainBundle:Table2',
            'choice_label' => 'numero' // MAGIC read next paragraph, it is a private variable
        ))
```

Like is in documentation writed:

> If the entity object does not have a __toString() method the choice_label option is needed.

Use this solution because its native symfony solution for this situations :)

I hope i will help you or the other people

Answer (score 1):

If you need information's table, you could create a constructor in your `Form class`

in your controller :

```
$emForm = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RelacionesDoctrineBundle:Adolecente');

$asignatura = new AsignaturasType($emForm);// your form class
```

---

in your form class

```
class AsignaturasType extends AbstractType {

      protected $repository;

          function __construct($repository)
             {
               $this->repository = $repository;
             }
}
```

and done! you use it:

```
  $findAdolecente    = $this->repository->findAll();
```